# Child route keeps triggering parent when ui-sref-active-eq is used (angular-ui-router)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a route in `angular-ui-router` that has child routes; I want links to those child routes to only be visible while on the parent route. They are present on a menu that is visible for the whole application, but each link depends on a url parameter in the parent to work, so it's imperative that they not be clickable when that parameter doesn't exist.

So, the setup is like this;

```
.state('route1', {
   url: '/route1/:id',
   views: { 'main@': { template: '<route1-component></route1-component>' } }
})
.state('route1.child1', {
   url: '/child1',
   views: { 'main@': { template: '<route1-child1-component></route1-child1-component>' } }
})
```

I've gotten the functionality of hiding them to work using the `ui-sref` in combination with `ui-sref-active-eq`, using this layout...

```
<div ui-sref="route1" ui-sref-active-eq="visible" hidden>
   <a ui-sref="route1.child1" ui-sref-opts="{ location: true, inherit: true, relative: true }">CHILD 1</a>
</div>
```

This works fine at first; The link is only visible when we're on the `route1` route. The url it shows is `#/route1/1/child1`, including the `:id` parameter of the current url.

But when I click on the link, the URL flashes as `#/route1/1/child1` for a brief instant, but then `route1` renders again.

If I remove the `ui-sref-active-eq` portion, it correctly routes to the child route. But then I've got the problem of it not being hidden otherwise.

Is there anything that can be done?

Please note, I am using **exclusively** angular 1.5+ **components**. I'm not using normal controllers or directives at all. It's all 100% components.

It's not quite perfect, but this is an example of how things are laid out, and I tried to make it clear how they're expected to function. I can't seem to get the `$state` within the directive to observe changes. https://plnkr.co/edit/rxjVbckhwxdYPRAX4uiU?p=preview

Comment: worst case create your own directive that uses `$state.includes()` or other utilities built into `$state`

Comment: I'm not sure how you would listen for state change there. It doesn't seem to work when I attach `$stateChangeStart` to `$rootScope` anywhere but within the `run` function of the module config.

Comment: can inject `$state` into directive also. create a demo that replicates problem

Comment: Yeah, that's not working. `.directive('uiSrefVisible', function () {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                controller: function($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
                    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
                        function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
                            console.log('test');
                        })
                },
                link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
                }
            }
        })`

Comment: That just doesn't work. It never fires off. The only place it fires off is within the initial `run` function.

Comment: why did you put it outside `link`? You can put a watch inside `link`. Not clear where this nav is either....create demo

Comment: Injecting it into the `link` function just yields `undefined`. I really can't make a demo, the program is pretty large.

Comment: you don't need the full app...just a minimal representation of this problem

Comment: It's not quite perfect, but this is an example of how things are laid out, and I tried to make it clear how they're expected to function. I can't seem to get the `$state` within the directive to observe changes. https://plnkr.co/edit/rxjVbckhwxdYPRAX4uiU?p=preview

Comment: Basically, `ROUTE 1 CHILD LINK` shouldn't be visible unless you're within `route1`. But the `ui-sref-active` and `ui-sref-active-eq` directives cause it not to transition correctly.

Comment: Also, trying to use the injected `$state` just throws undefined. It doesn't seem to pick up `$state`, `$stateProvider`, anything. It'll only find them in the controller function.

Comment: injecting $state in wrong place

Comment: I've never coded angular with pure javascript before. I've only done it with typescript. I've also never used directives; I only learned it recently, so I started with components. So I'm a bit confused about where it should even be injected, then.

Comment: So it should be more like this? https://plnkr.co/edit/rxjVbckhwxdYPRAX4uiU?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

following adds a controller to your sidenav component and uses `$stateChangeSuccess`  event and `$state.includes()` to update a boolean passed to `ng-show`

```
  .component('sidenav', {
    controller: function ($rootScope,$state) {
      var vm = this;
      vm.isRoute1=$state.includes('route1');
      $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(evt, to, from){
          vm.isRoute1=$state.includes('route1');
      });            
   },
    template: `
        <div  ng-show="$ctrl.isRoute1">
          <a ui-sref="route1.child1" ui-sref-opts="{ location: true, inherit: true, relative: true }">
            ROUTE 1 CHILD 1 LINK
          </a>
        </div>`

  })
```

I think this is the behavior you want ... not 100% sure though

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/Rb1NcEqZrBHc7AbpPOnG?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: Wow! It's not exactly the behavior, but it demonstrates the principle. I think I can easily enough abstract this out to something a bit more scalable. Thank you for working with me. This is honestly the first time I've written any angular in pure javascript, so it was pretty confusing, going from typescript down.

Comment: strongly suggest staying away from naming custom directives with prefixes that are very close to existing modules or you won't realize later on that they aren't part of that module

Comment: That was more just for example. Though I can't seem to get this to repeat in Typescript... it's very peculiar. I just can't seem to get the `$rootScope.$on` to fire off. It's really strange...

Comment: i did start doing this as directive and if you need scalability then directive might be better approach...then can pass in bindings though attributes

Comment: It doesn't make much sense, though. It works fine on the component controller in your example, but when I put it into the typescript, `$rootScope` is there. I can print it out. But `$on` never fires. It's just so caddywhompus.

Comment: In any event, I guess thats a problem for another question! Thank you again for the help.